# Is there a connection between $tanh(nx)$ and $\frac{nx}{1+nx}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is there a connection between $tanh(nx)$ and $\frac{nx}{1+nx}$?

Can I express $tanh(nx)$ using this expression?

Edit: $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Well, $\tanh(nx) = \frac{e^{2nx}+1}{e^{2nx}-1}= \frac{1-e^{-2nx}}{1+e^{2nx}}$. Conclude.

Comment: I know this but how to get something like $\frac{nx}{1+nx}$?

Comment: Why should it be $e^{2nx}\rightarrow nx$?

Comment: This is a very vague question. What kind of "connection" would you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\tanh(nx) = \frac{e^{2nx}-1}{e^{2nx}+1}.$$

Note as $x \to 0$ then $e^{2nx}$ can be approximated by $1 + 2nx$ so that then

$$\tanh(nx) = \frac{e^{2nx}-1}{e^{2nx}+1} \approx \frac{1+2nx - 1}{1 + 2nx + 1} = \frac{nx}{1+nx}.$$

So they're related in the sense that the latter approximates the former at $0$.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean since $\frac{nx}{1+nx}$ is not uniform convergent in $x=0$ than the same is for $\tanh(nx)$?

Comment: It might be good to ask that question separately. I'm not sure of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tanh(nx) = \frac{e^{2nx}-1}{e^{2nx}+1}= \frac{1-e^{-2nx}}{1+e^{-2nx}}$$
Use the second form and note that we have a clear difference here.... assuming $n$ is not a function of $x$ we have an exponential, which cannot be equated to a linear term. In other words, $nx \neq e^{-nx}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was trying to express that you can't write $e^{-2nx}$ as $nx$ for any $n$, and even if you tried the numerator would fail. I can just adjust it to the fact that an exponential cant be linear if you prefer though. I interpreted $n$ to potentially be a function since the OP did not specify, in which case I intended to show that the numerator and denominator are incompatible

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree. Having difficulty putting what I mean into words. Is the edit more fitting? I can still adjust if necessary.